# Flutter UI is still freezing when using isolate

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-isolates

I am developing an application in Flutter where I need to implement an image selection function like in instagram.
But there is an issue, my app UI is freezing when trying to get and compress files from user phone gallery.

This is my first experience with flutter isolates, but as far as i know it should work without freezes.

[Here is an image for a better understanding of what i want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXPz1.png)

This is a function that calls getFiles function in isolation.
Here i get paths of user phone gallery files and pass them to another function in order to compress and get files for rendering.

```
Future fetchImages({ bool fetchMore = false, bool force = false }) async {
    if (!fetchMore) {
      setState(() => fetched = false);
    }
    if (force) {
      assetsCount = await assetPathEntity!.assetCountAsync;
      page = 0;

      files.clear();
    }
    if (assetsCount == 0 || page >= (assetsCount / pageSize)) {
      return setState(() => fetched = true);
    }
    final assetEntities = await assetPathEntity!.getAssetListPaged(page: page++, size: pageSize);
    lastCompletedIndex = files.length;

    final receivePort = ReceivePort();
    final completer = Completer();

    getFiles(receivePort.sendPort, assetEntities);

    try {
      receivePort.listen((filesPaths) {
        for (final filePath in filesPaths) {
          files.add({
            "path": filePath,
            "compressedFile": null,
          });
        }

        if (scaledFile == null && files.isNotEmpty) {
          scaledFile = File(files.first["path"]);
        }
        compressAlbumImages();
        completer.complete();
        setState(() => fetched = true);
      }).onError((_) {
        compressAlbumImages();
        completer.complete();
        setState(() => fetched = true);
      });

      await Future.wait([completer.future]);
    } catch (_) { }
    finally {
      receivePort.close();
    }
  }
```

This is getFiles function that runs in isolation

```
void getFiles(SendPort sendPort, List<AssetEntity> assetEntities) async {
  final List<String> filesPaths = [];

  for (final assetEntity in assetEntities) {
    try {
      final file = await assetEntity.file;

      if (file != null) {
        filesPaths.add(file.path);
      }
    } catch (_) { }
  }
  sendPort.send(filesPaths);
}
```

This is a function that calls compressImages function and adds any value to refresh the list of images
Here i pass the paths and get compressed files for rendering.

```
void compressAlbumImages() async {
    final receivePort = ReceivePort();
    final completer = Completer();

    compressImages(receivePort.sendPort, files, lastCompletedIndex);

    try {
      receivePort.listen((compressedFilesWithPath) {
        files = compressedFilesWithPath;
        fileStreamCt.sink.add(1);
        completer.complete();
      }).onError((_) {
        completer.complete();
      });
      await Future.wait([completer.future]);
    } catch (_) {}
    finally {
      receivePort.close();
    }
    return;
  }
```

This is an image compression function that runs in isolation

```
void compressImages(SendPort sendPort, List<Map<String, dynamic>> files, int startFromIndex) async {
  final List<String> filesToBeRemoved = [];

  for (int idx = startFromIndex; idx < files.length; idx++) {
    final file = files[idx];

    try {
      final compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
        file["path"],
        quality: 20,
        percentage: 20,
        targetHeight: 300,
        targetWidth: 300,
      );

      file["compressedFile"] = compressedFile;
    } catch (_) {
      filesToBeRemoved.add(file["path"]);
    }
  }

  if (filesToBeRemoved.isEmpty) {
    return sendPort.send(files);
  }
  final compressedFilesWithPaths = files
      .whereNot((element) => filesToBeRemoved.contains(element["path"]))
      .toList();

  sendPort.send(compressedFilesWithPaths);
}
```

And finally i render compressed images

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: fileStreamCt.stream,
  builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Text("LOADING...");
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("AN ERROR OCCURRED");
    }
    return buildAlbumImages();
  }
);
```

Render like this

```
Image.file(compressedImage);
```

If in short - When i'm getting user phone gallery files && compress them, my app UI starts freezing.
I don't know why it's freezing.

I tried the same process but with file.readAsBytes() and to render like Image.memory(compressedFileBytes), but it was useless.

I would be very grateful for any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asynchronous programming and concurrent programming are different things. `async`/`await` belong to the former, and `Isolate` belongs to the latter. Your isolate is halting your main thread because right now your isolate _is_ your main thread. At no point in this code do you call `Isolate.spawn` or other functions that spin up a new isolate to run in parallel to the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you never actually create an isolate. The 'isolate code' in `getFile`, `compressImages` etc simply runs on the main isolate and indeed will block the UI.

Per [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency#how-isolates-work), you create an isolate with `Isolate.spawn` and pass *only* the sendPort. The isolate then must send back a receivePort, and the main thread uses that port to send the data you want to isolate to process (like `assetEntities`), processes it and sends the results back to the main thread.  It's a bit complicated, and requires different function signatures than you have here.

Fortunately, a much easier way to accomplish what you want (still using Isolates that won't block the UI) is to use the [`compute`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html) function from the `dart:async` package:
Change the signature of your `getFiles` function to `Future<List<String>> getFiles(List<AssetEntity> assetEntities) async` and do in it what you need to do, returning the list of `filesPaths` as you do now. Importantly, `getFiles` must be a top level or a static function, it cannot be a regular class method. Then, where you need the calculation done you use something like `var filesPaths = await compute(getFiles, assetEntities)`. Now, the `getFiles` function is called in an isolate, and the return value is given back to you on the main isolate. The nice thing is that now this looks a lot like regular `await` call, no need for sendPorts etc. You can do the same thing for your other heavy calculation methods.

One (big) constraint with isolates is the type of argument you can pass to and from an isolate, see [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html). Those same constraints apply here, because under the hood the `compute` function also uses sendPorts etc.